# Can anyone recommend a good C/C++ RESTful framework

Tags: c++, c, rest

Rather than possibly reinventing the wheel (by "rolling my own") - I thought I'd ask in here first.

Anyone knows where I can download a good C/C++ RESTful framework?. I have had a quick look on google, but there is nothing too impressive so far - maybe someone in here has written one already (that they dont mind sharing), or may know a lik to a good one (preferably, they have already used it before)

Comment: Are you being forced to use C/C++? If not, you'll have a much easier time going with C# and WCF. Its really easy once you understand how WCF works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just seen [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/restcgi/files/), it may be what I'm looking for. Could be useful for others too

Comment: someone used it is it good for production?

Answer (score 2):

A solution to this would be the **ffead-cpp** framework, It provides the [**HTTPRequest**](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp/source/browse/trunk/ffead-server/src/HttpRequest.cpp), [**HTTPResponse**](http://code.google.com/p/ffead-cpp/source/browse/trunk/ffead-server/include/HttpResponse.h) and the **HTTPResponseParser** utility classes. Once you get hold of the HTTP Request parameters, developing a rest-full service would be a walk in the park.