# C++ web service

Tags: c++, web-services, restlet

I have a C++ program, and I want to make it as a web service listening to http request. I am a newbie to web development. Could some one give me a guild to tools/library/APIs that can help me build it. I know Java program usually restlet. What is the equivalent of restlet for C++?

Comment: gSOAP is the first result for "c++ web services" and sounds like what you want. http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html

Comment: SOAP is a more complicate protocol then REST used in restlet. REST means encoding information as simple strings with more complex information passed as request body. A C++ REST library was recommended [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961238/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-c-c-restful-framework)

Comment: I am looking at CPPCMS, CPPSERV, and A Stream Socket API for C++:http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~dgame/sockets/socketsC++/sockets.html, can anyone tell me which is better, and the comparison between them

Comment: What was the reason for not selecting an answer?

Comment: Asynchronous C++11 RESTful framework: https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend C++ web toolkit

http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt

or

cppcms.sourceforge.net

Comment: that's the first google result I am with wt :) |jo napot

Comment: I am looking at CppCMS, but couldn't find an example that illustrates how to use for my purpose.

Comment: plus, I also found this: CPPSERV, comparing to CppCMS, which is better ?

Comment: @emilywuq: it is primarily opinion based, but I would use CppCMS. Any reason why you have not selected an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

The old, classic way to make existing C/C++ executable available on the web is through [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). A web server that supports CGI can be configured to interpret an URL as a reference to a CGI script that can be directly your executable or a simple wrapper around it. The web for fields are provided as standard input and the program's output becomes the server response.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar in Python and I am also newcomer on this field. You might be interested in `sockets`, see: http://goo.gl/r6X4u, http://goo.gl/enffd

Answer (score 0):

The [QxtWeb](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/tech-web.html) module provides tools for creating web services using Qt.

Also, if you are using Visual C++ then [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235434%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is an introduction how to create web services.